# cas oauth google fail

Tags: oauth-2.0, cas

I am trying to integrate CAS into our web application to authenticate via OAuth 2.0, and i have downloaded the demo application from "https://github.com/leleuj/cas-oauth-demo-3.5.x."(client demo). and deployed it in tomcat7, but exception is thrown when authenticate with Google account. i have tried to write another provider and authentication is ok, but can not be redirected to my original web page.

### Below is the error message. Does anyone be familar with CAS Oauth? look forward to your answers, thanks.

### {"failure":"true","exception.message":"org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing org.jasig.cas.support.oauth.web.flow.OAuthAction@1077092 in state 'oauthAction' of flow 'login' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'","exception.stacktrace":"org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing org.jasig.cas.support.oauth.web.flow.OAuthAction@1077092 in state 'oauthAction' of flow 'login' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'\r\n\tat org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:60)\r\n\tat org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:77)\r\n\tat org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)\r\n\tat org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)\r\n\tat org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)\r\n\tat org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)\r\n\tat org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)\r\n\tat org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:535)\r\n\tat org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:366)\r\n\tat org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:225)\r\n\tat org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:140)\r\n\tat org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:193)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)\r\n\tat org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service_aroundBody2(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:128)\r\n\tat org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service_aroundBody3$advice(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:57)\r\n\tat org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:1)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)\r\n\tat com.github.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:63)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)\r\nCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException\r\n\tat org.jasig.cas.support.oauth.web.flow.OAuthAction.doExecute(OAuthAction.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)\r\n\tat org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)\r\n\t... 45 more\r\n"}

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of the OAuth support for CAS. Google OAuth 1.0 support has been removed by Google. You have to switched to Google OAuth 2.0 support by using the *Google2Provider* class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for jleleu's clarification. i still have one issue with CAS OAuth. 

I have tried SinaWeiboApi20, and the authentication is ok, but i found the service is null in OAuthAction, thus it can not be redirected to original web page. so i put the original page's url in parameter "state", which can be restored after authenticated by the SinaWeibo, and i have to add additional action to get this parameter and convert it to service before it can work(redirect it to the original page). but when i open other URLs, it still redirect me to CAS login page. 
anything wrong is my implementation?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how you used the SinaWeiboApi20 : did you create some provider for this API ?

Comment: yes, i have created the provider for SinaWeiboApi20, which extends BaseOAuth20Provider, and implemented the methods such as  getAuthorizationUrl(final UserSession session), getAccessToken(OAuthCredential credential), extractCredentialFromParameters (just call super.extractCredentialFromParameters) and etc. the access token can be obtained and i can get the user profile too.

Comment: So great ! I'd appreciate you to push me back your contribution (https://github.com/leleuj/pac4j project). The "state" parameter is not handled by default, take a look at the FacebookProvider which has a specific support for that...

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I'm using cas-oauth-client-demo(v4.0) and it helps much. i am planning to extend it in our application.